# Debugging stops after a few seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create an application similar to [Blog // PersonalPortal // github.com](https://github.com/unpub777/PersonalPortal/tree/master/PersonalPortal)

I copied part of the application.
I am running debugging.
The start page appears, then after 3-5 seconds the debugging stops.

**Question.**
Why does debugging stop?

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WebAppCore
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
 // 
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WebAppCore
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
              services.AddMvc();
             // services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            //app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            //{
            //    endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            //    {
            //        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            //    });
            //});

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

        }
    }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace PersonalPortal.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
  @page
@model WebAppCore.Views.Home.IndexModel
@{
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>*** Тестовая страница ***</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

**BlogController.cs**

```
using Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebAppCore.Services.Interfaces;
using WebAppCore.ViewModels;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PersonalPortal.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class BlogController : Controller
    {
        IBlogService _blogService;

        public BlogController(IBlogService blogService)
        {
            _blogService = blogService;
        }

        [Route("page")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<Page<PostLiteViewModel>> GetPosts(int pageIndex, string tag)
        {
            return await _blogService.GetPosts(pageIndex, tag);
        }

        [Route("post")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<Post> GetPost(int postId)
        {
            return await _blogService.GetPost(postId);
        }

        [Route("comment")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task AddComment([FromBody] AddCommentRequest request)
        {
            await _blogService.AddComment(request);
        }

        [Authorize]
        [Route("comment")]
        [HttpDelete]
        public async Task DeleteComment(int commentId)
        {
            await _blogService.DeleteComment(commentId);
        }

        [Authorize]
        [Route("post")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task AddPost([FromBody] AddPostRequest request)
        {
            await _blogService.AddPost(request);
        }

        [Authorize]
        [Route("post")]
        [HttpDelete]
        public async Task DeletePost(int postId)
        {
            await _blogService.DeletePost(postId);
        }

        [Route("tags")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<List<string>> GetTags()
        {
            return await _blogService.GetTags();
        }
    }
}
```

**IdentityController.cs**

```
    // 
using WebAppCore.Services.Interfaces;
using WebAppCore.Helpers;
using WebAppCore.ViewModels;

// 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;

namespace PersonalPortal.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class IdentityController : Controller
    {
        IIdentityService _service;

        public IdentityController(IIdentityService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        [Route("token")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Token([FromBody]IdentityViewModel model)
        {
            var identity = await GetIdentity(model.Username, model.Password);
            if (identity == null)
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            // создаем JWT-токен
            var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: AuthOptions.ISSUER,
                    audience: AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
                    notBefore: now,
                    claims: identity.Claims,
                    expires: now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(AuthOptions.LIFETIME)),
                    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));
            var encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

            var response = new
            {
                access_token = encodedJwt,
                username = identity.Name
            };

            return Ok(response);
        }

        private async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GetIdentity(string userName, string password)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity identity = null;
            var user = await _service.GetUser(userName);
            if (user != null)
            {
                var sha256 = new SHA256Managed();
                var passwordHash = Convert.ToBase64String(sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)));
                if (passwordHash == user.Password)
                {
                    var claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, user.Login),
                    };
                    identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Token", ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
                }
            }
            return identity;
        }
    }
}
```

**Picture-1**
[image]

**Picture-2**
  [image]